# Is it possible to use SSLEngine with *Blocking* I/O

Tags: java

I am trying to integrate some two code bases. One code base uses blocking I/O. The other code base uses non-blocking I/O.

The hook where I can integrate the two of these is a plain old-fashioned acceptor thread.

This acceptor thread reads the sub-protocol information from the socket and then based on the sub-protocol name forwards to the corresponding handler.

The other side of the code has it's own selector thread but only exposes a higher level set of constructs.

So basically I need to - in the acceptor thread's spawned worker thread - fire up the SSLEngine validate some sub-protocol information and then hand the whole thing off to the other code base's selector thread.

To make things more complicated, there is a fall-back path on the second code base whereby if it gets a `Socket` that was not opened with a `SocketChannel` it will drop down to blocking mode... and this is the bit that is causing me issues...

Namely it is not safe for me to assume that `Socket.getChannel()!=null`

So my `SSLEngine` code needs to take account of that possibility and set up the `SSLEngine` without using the non-blocking I/O APIs...

So far, I keep hitting blocking read calls that stall the engine...

**Question** does anyone know of any examples where `SSLEngine` has been used with a traditional `InputStream/OutputStream` rather than with a `SocketChannel`

Comment: Blocking read calls don't stall the engine. They block in `read()`. Your point is unclear. Using the `SSLEngine` in blocking mode is a lot easier than in non-blocking mode, as you don't have to worry about operations such as tasks that may be concurrently in progress: you can do them inline.

Answer (score 0):

Yes for handshake.
It is sad that we can't use SSLSocket.getSession for SSLEngine.
But we cat use SSLEngine in blocking mode.
See jdk1.8.0_112/sample/nio/server/ChannelIOSecure.java

Blocking:

```
method1(){
    ....
    socketChannel.configureBlocking(true);
    SSLEngine engine = sslContext.createSSLEngine();
    engine.setUseClientMode(false);//server
    engine.setNeedClientAuth(true);
    this.outNetBB = ByteBuffer.allocate(engine.getSession().getPacketBufferSize());
    outNetBB.position(0);
    outNetBB.limit(0);
    this.inNetBB = ByteBuffer.allocate(engine.getSession().getPacketBufferSize());
    this.requestBB = ByteBuffer.allocate(engine.getSession().getApplicationBufferSize());
    this.hsBB = ByteBuffer.allocate(engine.getSession().getApplicationBufferSize());
    initialHSComplete = false;

    while(initialHSComplete != true)
       doHandshake(socketChannel, engine, null);
    }



 private boolean tryFlush(ByteBuffer bb, SocketChannel socketChannel) throws IOException {
    socketChannel.write(bb);
    return !bb.hasRemaining();
}


private SSLEngineResult.HandshakeStatus doTasks(SSLEngine sslEngine) {

    Runnable runnable;

    /*
     * We could run this in a separate thread, but
     * do in the current for now.
     */
    while ((runnable = sslEngine.getDelegatedTask()) != null) {
        runnable.run();
    }
    return sslEngine.getHandshakeStatus();
}


private ByteBuffer outNetBB;
int netBBSize;
private ByteBuffer inNetBB;
int appBBSize;
private ByteBuffer requestBB;
private ByteBuffer hsBB;

private boolean initialHSComplete; // Handshake complete status

HandshakeStatus initialHSStatus = HandshakeStatus.NEED_UNWRAP; //server

private boolean doHandshake(SocketChannel sc, SSLEngine sslEngine, SelectionKey sk) throws IOException {



    SSLEngineResult result;

    if (initialHSComplete) {
        return initialHSComplete;
    }

    /*
     * Flush out the outgoing buffer, if there's anything left in
     * it.
     */
    if (outNetBB.hasRemaining()) {
        System.out.println("doha wtf");

        if (!tryFlush(outNetBB, sc)) {
            return false;
        }

        // See if we need to switch from write to read mode.

        switch (initialHSStatus) {


        // Is this the last buffer?

        case FINISHED:
            initialHSComplete = true;
            // Fall-through to reregister need for a Read.

        case NEED_UNWRAP:
            if (sk != null) {
                sk.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ);
            }
            break;
        }

        return initialHSComplete;
    }


    switch (initialHSStatus) {

    case NEED_UNWRAP:
        System.out.println("before read");
        if (sc.read(inNetBB) == -1) {
            sslEngine.closeInbound();
            return initialHSComplete;
        }
        System.out.println("after read");

        needIO:
            while (initialHSStatus == HandshakeStatus.NEED_UNWRAP) {
                System.out.println("initialHSStatus"+initialHSStatus);
                resizeRequestBB();    // expected room for unwrap
                inNetBB.flip();
                result = sslEngine.unwrap(inNetBB, requestBB);
                inNetBB.compact();
                System.out.println("result"+result);
                initialHSStatus = result.getHandshakeStatus();

                switch (result.getStatus()) {

                case OK:
                    switch (initialHSStatus) {
                    case NOT_HANDSHAKING:
                        throw new IOException(
                                "Not handshaking during initial handshake");

                    case NEED_TASK:
                        initialHSStatus = doTasks(sslEngine);
                        break;

                    case FINISHED:
                        initialHSComplete = true;
                        break needIO;
                    }

                    break;

                case BUFFER_UNDERFLOW:
                    // Resize buffer if needed.
                    netBBSize = sslEngine.getSession().getPacketBufferSize();
                    if (netBBSize > inNetBB.capacity()) {
                        resizeResponseBB();
                    }

                    /*
                     * Need to go reread the Channel for more data.
                     */
                    if (sk != null) {
                        sk.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ);
                    }
                    break needIO;

                case BUFFER_OVERFLOW:
                    // Reset the application buffer size.
                    appBBSize =
                    sslEngine.getSession().getApplicationBufferSize();
                    break;

                default: //CLOSED:
                    throw new IOException("Received" + result.getStatus() +
                            "during initial handshaking");
                }
                System.out.println("bottom of needIO");
            }  // "needIO" block.
        System.out.println("after needIO "+initialHSStatus);
        /*
         * Just transitioned from read to write.
         */
        if (initialHSStatus != HandshakeStatus.NEED_WRAP) {
            break;
        }

        // Fall through and fill the write buffers.

    case NEED_WRAP:
        /*
         * The flush above guarantees the out buffer to be empty
         */
        outNetBB.clear();
        result = sslEngine.wrap(hsBB, outNetBB);
        outNetBB.flip();

        initialHSStatus = result.getHandshakeStatus();
        System.out.println("result wrap="+result);
        switch (result.getStatus()) {
        case OK:

            if (initialHSStatus == HandshakeStatus.NEED_TASK) {
                initialHSStatus = doTasks(sslEngine);
            }
            System.out.println("here");
            if (sk != null) {
                sk.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
            }
            System.out.println("here2");
            break;

        default: // BUFFER_OVERFLOW/BUFFER_UNDERFLOW/CLOSED:
            throw new IOException("Received" + result.getStatus() +
                    "during initial handshaking");
        }
        break;

    default: // NOT_HANDSHAKING/NEED_TASK/FINISHED
        throw new RuntimeException("Invalid Handshaking State" +
                initialHSStatus);
    } // switch

    return initialHSComplete;
}


/*private void tryFlush(SocketChannel sc) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("flush"+outNetBB);
    sc.write(outNetBB);
    if (!outNetBB.hasRemaining())
        outNetBB.clear();
}*/


//}
//}

private void resizeResponseBB() {
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(netBBSize);
    inNetBB.flip();
    bb.put(inNetBB);
    inNetBB = bb;
}

protected void resizeRequestBB() {
    int remaining = appBBSize;
    if (requestBB.remaining() < remaining) {
        // Expand buffer for large request
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(requestBB.capacity() * 2);
        requestBB.flip();
        bb.put(requestBB);
        requestBB = bb;
    }
}
```

To change to non-blocking add:

```
socketChannel.configureBlocking(true);
Selector selector = Selector.open();
SelectionKey sk = socketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);

while(initialHSComplete != true){
    selector.select();
    doHandshake(socketChannel, engine, sk);
```

Comment: Yes for the whiole SSL connection lifetime, not just the handshake. NB You mean `configureBlocking(false)`. This code will throw `IllegalBlockingModeException`.

Comment: IllegalBlockingModeException could be only if your CannelSocket register with selector. You can cancel Selection key, like this: `socketChannel.keyFor(readSelector).cancel();`